# Cambiar puerto localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: wamp

A ver si alguien me echa una mano porque no encuentro la solución.
Cuando entro desde el enlace de la aplicación a phpmyadmin me la abre en "http://localhost/phpmyadmin/" y lo que necesito es abrirla en "http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/", cómo puedo cambiarle el puerto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En el archivo **httpd.conf** debes buscar la línea que dice `Listen 80` y cambiarla por `Listen 8080`

Por lo general este archivo esta en `Apache\conf\`